# Bash - Sudo authentication using stdin and EOF

Tags: bash, sudo, eof

I'm having trouble to authenticate using `sudo -S`, `bash -c` and `EOF`.

In this code below:

- 1st `sudo` is OK
- 2nd `sudo` authentication is OK, but not with the
  expected output
- 3rd `sudo` authentication is OK, but not with the
  expected output
- 4th `sudo` authentication is OK, but I don't seem
  to be able to write a file
- 5th `sudo` can't authenticate

--

```
#!/bin/bash

pass="my_pass\n"
#echo -e $pass

ssh -T my_user@my_server << EOF
    whoami
    pwd
    echo $HOSTNAME
    (sleep 3; echo -e $pass; sleep 3) | sudo -S -u batchuser whoami
    (sleep 3; echo -e $pass; sleep 3) | sudo -S -H -u batchuser bash -c "pwd"
    (sleep 3; echo -e $pass; sleep 3) | sudo -S -u batchuser bash -c "echo $HOSTNAME"
    (sleep 3; echo -e $pass; sleep 3) | sudo -S -u batchuser bash -c "touch test"
    (sleep 3; echo -e $pass; sleep 3) | sudo -S -u batchuser bash -c << TEST1
        sleep 10; echo -e $pass; sleep 3
        whoami
        pwd
    TEST1
EOF
```

**Output:**

```
my_user@my_pc> ./test_ssh.sh
my_user@my_server's password:              <-- I wrote the password here
my_user
/home/my_user
my_pc                                      <-- It's not 'my_server'
Mot de passe de my_user: batchuser
Mot de passe de my_user: /home/my_user     <-- It's not '/home/batchuser'
Mot de passe de my_user: my_pc             <-- It's not 'my_server'
Mot de passe de I86671: touch: cannot touch `test': Permission denied
Mot de passe de my_user: Sorry, try again.
Mot de passe de my_user: Sorry, try again.
Mot de passe de my_user: Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts
my_user@my_pc>
```

Do you know how I can pass the password with `EOF`?
And why the output of `bash -c` is not what expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that in HereDocument the environmental variables are expanded in the calling shell by default. You can prevent this behaviour by using `"EOF"` with quotes as a starting delimiter or escaping variables like `\$HOSTNAME`.
You should seriously read `man bash` about `Here Documents`. It's like three short paragraphs.

The problem with the second sudo is that although `-H` is used, that only sets the `$HOME` envvar, but does not change the directory. `"cd; pwd"` should solve that.

From `man sudo`:

> -H, --set-home
>
> Request that the security policy set the HOME environment variable to
>   the home directory specified by the target user's password database
>   entry.  Depending on the policy, this may be the default behavior.

The third sudo might present a bigger problem as that variable is nested even deeper. For `\$HOSTNAME` it will be the same of course, but for other envvars you might have to pile a bunch of backslashes in front to protect them. Think `\\\$UID`.

As for `touch test`, you have to change directory to somewhere where you have permission to write that file or handle the permissions somehow.

The problem with the last sudo is that both the pipe and the HereDoc are set as `stdin` for the `sudo` command, not for `bash`, so somehow those two got mixed up. 
What you want here is:

```
(sleep 3; echo -e $pass; sleep 3) | sudo -S -u batchuser bash -c "
    whoami
    pwd
"
```

Last minor thing is that (imho) writing your code like this might make a better read as `sleep` is also unneccessary:

```
<<<$pass  sudo -S -p "" bash -c "cd; pwd"
```

Comment: I never took the time to thank you. Your last tip rocks. :)